# passing java property file keys via maven command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line, bamboo, properties-file

I've a config.properties files under src/main/java/configs/config.properties which contains the following profile:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <no_of_files>${no_of_files}</no_of_files>
            <no_of_rows>${no_of_rows}</no_of_rows>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

my config.properties file contains

`no_of_rows = ${no_of_rows}
 no_of_files = ${no_of_files}`

I'm using the following maven command to pass these properties via the command line

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.project.App" -Dno_of_rows=4 -Dno_of_files=3
```

but it results into

```
[ERROR] Resolving expression: '${no_of_files}': Detected the following recursive expression cycle in 'no_of_files': [no_of_files] @
```

I've looked into other similar answers on stackoverflow but I think I'm still not getting the right way.

I need this to run the project using a bamboo job.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any Maven funkiness to do this:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String ...args) {

        // Load value from -Dno_of_files=
        Integer noOfFiles = Integer.getInteger("no_of_files");

        // Load value from -Dno_of_rows=
        Integer noOfRows = Integer.getInteger("no_of_rows");
    }

}
```

The config.properties and maven profile are not needed at all.

If you really want to generate values into a properties file then that is a more complicated answer.